# RxDom: not working when new id created

Tags: javascript, ajax, rxjs, rxjs-dom

I'm using [Reactive Extension DOM](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM) for listening event from DOM. Here is my sample code:

```
var input = document.getElementById('test_id');
var source = Rx.DOM.change(input);
var subscription = source.subscribe(
        function (x) {
          console.log(x);
        },
        function (err) {
          console.log('Error: ' + err);
        },
        function () {
          console.log('Completed');
        });
```

This code works when `test_id` is on page when `document.ready` finish. But I'm using AJAX request, so `test_id` just appears after a time when ajax request is sent and received on client. How can I make RxDom notify this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the Observable again.

When you call `document.getElementById('test_id');` and the element with id `test_id` doesn't exist it returns null. Therefore there's no way to "refresh" `source` Observable because it doesn't even know what DOM element it should "refresh".

So the only way is to create the Observable after you append HTML from your Ajax call.

Comment: wow. thanks for letting me know about this. One other question is: how can I make other elements subcribe to this source. thanks

Comment: @TrầnKimDự It's just an Observable, you subscribe to it like to any other Observable. Btw, what do you mean by "elements subscribe"? DOM elements can't subscribe to anything.

Comment: my meaning is: for example. I have an `input a`. when input a change, two elements named b and c will know and "do something". as code above, I must do manually: when receiving change signal from a, I must run do_something on same function. I want to reverse action.

Comment: You'll do it exactly the same way you're doing it right now. Input `a` will on each change update also `b` and `c`. Input's `b` and `c` can't update update automatically, somebody has to trigger the update which is `a`.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. so RxJS doesn't support recursive observer. It means: if a depends on b. b depends on c. so when chaning a doesn't changing c ?

Comment: @TrầnKimDự I doesn't work like this automatically but of course you can make the update manually.